# How to optimize or minimize a function for multiple arrays in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, data-fitting, scipy-optimize

I have multiple arrays to which I would like to fit an exponential function of the form given below:

[image]

I have five arrays in the MWE, y1, y2, y3 ..., y5; with M and N takes values shown in MWE. Now I would like to find the optimum value of A, E, m, and n such that residuals are minimized.

The MWE given below does this individually for each array y1, or y2, or y3; giving me (A1, E1, m1, n1), (A2, E2, m2, n2), ... (A5, E5, m5, n5). How can I apply optimization for all the arrays such that for a particular value of A, E, m, and n (i.e., same values of A, E, m, and n) gives me the least error?

**MWE**

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def f(params, y, M, N):
    A, E, m, n, = params
    residuals = y - (A * np.exp(E*x/1000) * (M ** m) * (N ** n))
    objective = (residuals**2).sum()
    return objective

x = np.array([1.170, 1.194, 1.223, 1.255, 1.282, 1.325, 1.358, 1.389, 1.435, 1.471])
y_1 = np.array([16.96, 18.45, 20.58, 21.62, 27.22, 33.98, 41.32, 55.64, 72.66, 95.68])
y_2 = np.array([22.74, 25.69, 34.54, 35.77, 40.88, 45.53, 60.12, 72.65, 91.54, 102.58])
y_3 = np.array([26.11, 21.99, 26.88, 31.63, 41.06, 45.47, 59.04, 60.11, 79.79, 97.79])
y_4 = np.array([33.73, 36.01, 35.12, 35.94, 47.02, 56.55, 63.94, 66.78, 96.06, 116.07])
y_5 = np.array([30.87, 33.09, 32.51, 41.72, 42.75, 54.52, 63.02, 78.15, 89.02, 102.54])

M = np.array([40, 20, 20, 15, 12])
N = np.array([0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 1.5])

result = optimize.minimize(f, [45, 2000, -1.0, -0.5], y_1)
A1, E1, m1, n1 = result.x
y_predicted_1 = (A1 * np.exp(E1*x/1000) * (40 ** m1) * (0.50 ** n1))

result = optimize.minimize(f, [45, 2000, -1.0, -0.5], y_2)
A2, E2, m2, n2 = result.x
y_predicted_2 = (A2 * np.exp(E2*x/1000) * (40 ** m2) * (0.50 ** n2))

result = optimize.minimize(f, [45, 2000, -1.0, -0.5], y_3)
A3, E3, m3, n3 = result.x
y_predicted_3 = (A3 * np.exp(E3*x/1000) * (40 ** m3) * (0.50 ** n3))

result = optimize.minimize(f, [45, 2000, -1.0, -0.5], y_4)
A4, E4, m4, n4 = result.x
y_predicted_4 = (A4 * np.exp(E4*x/1000) * (40 ** m4) * (0.50 ** n4))

result = optimize.minimize(f, [45, 2000, -1.0, -0.5], y_5)
A5, E5, m5, n5 = result.x
y_predicted_5 = (A5 * np.exp(E5*x/1000) * (40 ** m5) * (0.50 ** n5))
```

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but what if you were just to concatenate x 5 times and append all the ys together?

Answer (score 0):

You're actually almost there. Just use more than one data as argument (works because of the way how you designed your `f`):

```
result = optimize.minimize(f, [45, 2000, -1., -.5], [y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4, y_5])
A_, E_, m_, n_ = result.x
y_predicted_all = (A_ * np.exp(E_*x/1000) * (40 ** m_) * (0.50 ** n_))
```

Then you get these residuals:

```
Residuals (overall): 
1: 1361.14349
2: 107.87036
3: 165.67150
4: 713.73400
5: 358.97836

Residuals (individual): 
1: 53.10579
2: 72.27874
3: 76.72340
4: 206.37223
5: 60.04984
```

So slightly worse than individual fits, which is expected. Some of them are then pretty off, such as y_1, but the others can be pretty decent.

[image]
[image]

Comment: My apologies, there were a few errors in the question. The values of 'M' and 'N' were constant in the previous question. The values of 'M' and 'N' are not constant, question edited to reflect this.

Comment: you can just feed more arguments to your fitting function